# copying columns from selected rows to another sheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

the user should choose some rows (not necessarily beneath each other), then some columns from each row will be copied to another sheet, how can I achieve this ? 
I have tried  application.inputbox , but it doesn't seem to work with ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Not super efficient, but it should get the job done if I'm understanding what you're looking for. This will generate an array of all the rows that have the first cell in the row highlighted. Hope this helps.

```
Sub macro1()
Dim a As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim numRowsToCheck As Integer
Dim rows() As Integer
Dim length As Integer

Set a = Selection
numRowsToCheck = 100
length = 0
For i = 1 To numRowsToCheck
    If Not Application.Intersect(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1), a) Is Nothing Then
        length = length + 1
        ReDim Preserve rows(length)
        rows(length - 1) = i
    End If
Next i

MsgBox (rows(0) & "," & rows(1) & "," & rows(2)) 'Check results

For i = 0 To length - 1
    'Copy stuff from row i to wherever you want it to go
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked after I ignored the second FOR loop and wrote the action in the first FOR loop.